# UIBarButtonItem Done State Without Border

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

I have a `UIToolbar` where all the buttons have a style of `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`.  One of these buttons toggles a setting in my app and I would like to have some type of Selected state when that feature is enabled.

Since I am not using bordered buttons, setting the style to `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` would not work because the button would not match.  Is there an easy way to change to color of the icon on the button?

For a sample, look at the location button in the Maps app on the iPad.  It does exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing. You can set the background image with `initWithImage:style:target:action:` or supply a custom view with `initWithCustomView:`